# Person from same company got confidential information about me

Tags: law, inside-information

I had some troubles with moving in past months and therefore decided to instruct bank to transfer all mails to my job address. There the mail is sorted and (always so far) handed over to me.

Last time however, I got the mail, but since we had some changes of offices, they could not find me. Instead they (for some reason) opened the mail and then glued it back together. I still got that mail. They wrote short notice about confusion on a letter (with handwriting). When I got the mail it was clear that someone had opened it before. It was probably someone from my company.

The content of that letter were all my transactions in last 3 months and current balance.

I do not really care that they saw all that, however in my contract it says that I should not share my income information with noone and especially not with coworkers. That is fine, I did not share it, however other people did manage to get the information. My question is, can I just ignore this or do I have to tell this to anyone? Also, what are possible consequences?

Comment: I'm not sure how we can answer this, as any potential consequences would be specific to your company policy and your manager.

Comment: "That is fine, I did not share it" No, it is not fine, and you did share it. You arranged for your mail to be delivered to your office address. I don't see it too different from printing your salary statement through the common office printer without a PIN, and then "forgetting" to collect it.

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to go to whomever is in charge of the mail sorting and ask why it is that a piece of mail personally addressed to you was opened. In fact, I would go to your boss, and ask him to look into it.

It seems strange to me that any sort of "confusion" would result in an envelope address to you being opened by someone else. I would count it far more likely that someone was being a busy body and wanted to look at your statements.

However, the best way possible of avoiding such situations in the future is not to address sensitive pieces of mail to such a public venue. Sign up for e-statements, for example.

Possible consequences are that someone gets in trouble in the mail room, or that you yourself get in trouble (if you forwarded that personal mail to your office without prior approval, for example).

Comment: In some companies it is standard for all mail to be opened and then delivered.

Comment: Unless you had specific permission from your manager to receive personal mail at work, I might actually hold off saying anything. Receiving a special package at work once in a long while probably wouldn't be a big deal but the company might not appreciate using their mail department as your own personal concierge service. I might chalk this up as a lesson learned and move on.

Comment: _but the company might not appreciate using their mail department as your own personal concierge service._  
 +1 this is all that needs to be said. It was your personal mail routed to work. Yeah someone opened it, but the source is you introduced a potential problem by having that routed to work. If moving was a stress, you can put your mail on hold or route it to a family member.